# Pages Shown up but Texts are not display Angular

Tags: angular

i am a beginner of angular.i am  creating a small website on angular.i set routes successfully.but when i click the url links goes to the paticular page but text are not visible i don't why what i tried so far i attached below.

**Routes Sections**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: IndexComponent},
  {path: '/about', component: AboutComponent},
  {path: '/contact', component: ContactComponent}
];
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </div>
  </div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-group">
          <a href="/" class="list-group-item">Index</a>
          <a href="/about" class="list-group-item">About</a>
          <a href="/contact" class="list-group-item">Contact</a>
        </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**about.component.html**

```
<h1>About</h1>

<p>about works!</p>
```

**contact.component.html**

```
<p>contact works!</p>
```

Comment: I think you need to use `routerLink` instead of `href`.

Comment: <a routerLink ="/" class="list-group-item">Index</a>         i used like this way but now links are not shown up

Comment: What do you mean by not shown up? They are not displayed? Do you have any CSS that hides them? Or do they not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: IndexComponent},
  {path: '/about', component: AboutComponent},
  {path: '/contact', component: ContactComponent}
];
```

Instead of this use without slash

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {path: '', component: IndexComponent},
      {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
      {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent}
    ];
```

And also change the HTML page href to routerlink.

```
<a href="/" class="list-group-item">Index</a>
<a href="/about" class="list-group-item">About</a>
<a href="/contact" class="list-group-item">Contact</a>
```

like

```
<a routerLink="/" class="list-group-item">Index</a>
<a routerLink="/about" class="list-group-item">About</a>
<a routerLink="/contact" class="list-group-item">Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`In routing use this`

```
       const routes: Routes = [
     {path: '', component: IndexComponent},
     {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
     {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent}
      ];
```